# Command not found error in shell script from variable declaration

Tags: bash, shell

I've written a bash script and my script is failing, when all I'm doing is assigning a variable.

In my script I have the following declaration:

```
pcre-version="8.39"
```

After attempting to run the program I get this error:

```
-bash: pcre-version=8.39: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update:**

Variables cannot include hyphens. Removing them fixed the issue.

Comment: That's a weird error.  I would expect you to get 5 errors `httpd-version=2.4.23: command not found`, `apr-version-var=1.5.2: command not found`, etc.  It's very odd that you only get the error for pcre-version.  Or perhaps you have not accurately described what is happening.

Comment: At the end I meant only inputting the single command `pcre-version="8.39" ` was giving me an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-` is not a valid part of a variable name, try using `_` instead

<strike>It's being parsed like `pcre` `-` `version` `=` `"8.39"`</strike>
As chepner pointed out, there are no `IFS` characters in the original string, so it would not be subject to word splitting.  All those are valid filesystem characters (generally at least) so it's treated as a command name and searched for in `PATH`, which is not likely to be found, hence the error message

See [this related question on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/can-shell-variable-include-character) that talks about this

And it's a "Gotcha" [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/gotchas.html)

Comment: One nit: `pcre-version=8.39` is parsed as a single word.

Comment: Holy crap, that's crazy, how have I been using bash all this time without knowing that!